# jqueryui datepicker customize problem

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Greeting, 
I would like the jqueryui datapicker to use polish localization. Additionally, the dates have to be limited so it should not be possible to choose past dates. I have something like this:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pl']);
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: '+1Y ' });
    $("#StartDate").datepicker('option', $.datepicker.regional['pl']);
```

Limitation works find, but I cannot achieve polish localization. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you included http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-pl.js.

Also you don't need to set the option, setDefaults is enough.

`$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pl']); 
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: '+1Y ' });`